# Figuring out transistions

Tags: html, css, webkit, transition

i'm trying to figure out how to work some transitions? i've got an overlay div that pops up when a link is clicked but i'm trying to make it so it either fades into the div ontop or it just melts into it?

```
<html> 
<head> 

<style type="text/css"> 

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
}

.button { 
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
padding: 10px; 
background-color: transparent; 
font-weight:bold; 
text-decoration:none; 
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
} 

.blockpurp {
    background: purple;
}

.blockyell {
    background: yellow;
}

#cover { 
position:fixed; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
z-index:5; 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
display:none;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease; } 

#loginScreen, #loginScreen2 { 
padding: 20px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
overflow: scroll;
height:100%; 
width:100%; 
margin:0 auto; 
position:fixed; 
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index:10; 
display:none; 
background: rgba(0,0,0,1); 
border:0; 
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
} 

#loginscreen2 {
background: rgba(23,44,1,0.9); 
}

#loginScreen:target, #loginScreen:target + #cover, #loginScreen2:target, #loginScreen2:target + #cover{ 
display:block; 
opacity:9;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease; } 

.cancel { 
display:block; 
position:fixed; 
top:0px; 
right:0px; 
background: transparent; 
color:black; 
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
height:30px; 
width:35px; 
font-size:30px; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-align:center; 
font-weight:bold;
} 

</style> 

</head> 
<body> 

<div align="center">
<table align="center" width="900px" height="300px">
<td width="60%" class="blockpurp"><a href="#loginScreen" class="button">click</a></td>
<td width="40%" class="blockyell"><a href="#loginScreen2" class="button">click</a></td>
</table>
</div>

<div id="loginScreen"> 
LOL LOL LOL
<a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a> 
</div> 

<div id="cover" > 
</div> 

<div id="loginScreen2"> 
stuff stuff
<a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a> 
</div> 

<div id="cover" > 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

i tried using this code string:

```
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
```

but that doesn't seem to work? any ideas?

Comment: You need to use jquery in order to control mouse click event.

Comment: ah, that's my issue i wouldn't know where to begin with that..

Comment: @jacelysh You *definitely* do not need jQuery for this.

Comment: than how would it work without it @Luxelin?

Comment: @Guchie I was implying that you could do it with JavaScript. If you're not already using jQuery (you tagged the question with neither JavaScript nor jQuery), then there's no reason to include an entire library for one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you are going from `display:none` to `display:block`.  There is no real way to transition between the two using css.

Instead, you could keep them all displayed and in a fixed position, but change the appearance using z-index.

Below is an example of how you could do this.

HTML:

```
<div id="center">
    <table>
        <td class="blockpurp"><a href="#loginScreen" class="button">click</a></td>
        <td class="blockyell"><a href="#loginScreen2" class="button">click</a></td>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="loginScreen"> 
    <div>
LOL LOL LOL
    <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a> 
    </div>
</div> 

<div id="loginScreen2"> 
    <div>
stuff stuff
    <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (in need of some serious organization!):

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

#center {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

td a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
}

.blockpurp {
    background: purple;
    width: 60%;
}

.blockyell {
    background: yellow;
    width: 40%;
}

#loginScreen, #loginScreen2 {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
    color: white;
}

#loginScreen div, #loginScreen2 div {
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1); 
}

.cancel { 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    background: transparent; 
    color:black; 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    height:30px; 
    width:35px; 
    font-size:30px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-weight:bold;
} 

#loginScreen:target, #loginScreen2:target {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 3s;
    transition: opacity 3s;
    z-index:10;
}
```

I made the following changes in your html as well:

1. I took out the divs with the id 'cover'.  Unlike classes, you should never have more than one element with a particular id per page.  Id's should be completely unique.
2. I removed the inline styling.  Style everything within your stylesheet!

[Fiddle for reference](http://fiddle.jshell.net/q9f7L/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery in order to control mouse click event.

Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CrUqk/)

```
$(".sample").click(function(){
    $(".popup").css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'opacity': 1
        });    
});
```

Comment: Just to expand on your example, OP probably wants to have a `.popup.visible` class that is applied by the `click` handler, rather than editing the CSS directly.  If you want toggle behavior in your popup, for instance, you would then say: `$(".popup").toggleClass("visible");`.

Answer (score 0):

As of yet, there is no way to do an `HTML5` transition based on a link click. For now, you can toggle a class and attach the CSS transitions to the element being affected (which is faster + more lightweight anyway). If you attach the `transition` to the toggled class, then it will only do the transition when the toggled class is removed, not when it's added.

Here's an example that doesn't use jQuery—no reason to include an entire library, if you're not using it elsewhere.

**HTML**

```
<a id="clickme" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="test" class="clicked fun here">testing</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function (event) {
    var target = document.getElementById("test"),
        classes = test.className.split(" "),
        toggledClass = "clicked";
    if (!!~classes.indexOf(toggledClass)) {
        // same as if (classes.indexOf(toggledClass) > -1)
        test.className = classes.join(" ").replace(toggledClass, "");
    } else {
        test.className = classes.join(" ") + " " + toggledClass;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.clicked {
    color: red;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/H7epM/1/)

Comment: this would be extremely helpful if i knew anything about jquery haha, this entire thing is confusing to me.

Comment: @Guchie [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a JavaScript library. You probably don't need it (especially since you don't know what it is). To apply the above to your problem: `.clicked` is the class that will be toggled on and off on `div#test` on `a#clickme` clicks. Initially, you need to hide the `div` you want to overlay. Then, make a class with all the properties you want it to have when shown. Attach the JavaScript event handler to the link you're using and change `test` in `var target = document.getElementById("test")` to your `div`'s id.